# Running akka on windows 10 universal app (arm)

Tags: windows-10-universal, akka.net

Does anyone have an experience running actor system on windows10 (arm) as an universal app? Need to have some background job and akka looks like a go for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the situation was solved quickly by nuget :

```
Akka 1.1.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0
```

so need to wait for that :)